# Distinguish same page internal links traffic in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, internal-links

On my website, some pages have the same link to another page, in different places. For example, one is a button, another one is an anchor link.
I'd like to understand which ones draw more traffic.

I read it wasn't a good idea to add UTM tags for internal traffic.
I also read about event tracking, but this sounds pretty difficult to implement.

So I wonder if there are other easy solutions to get this insight.

Comment: Event tracking is usually implementing a small amount of JavaScript code that get triggered when a user clicks something.    The logic can either be coded or inserted with Google Tag Manager.    What is the hard part for you?

Answer (score 1):

Event tracking is actually pretty straight forward... You can see my answer [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/133508/using-google-analytics-to-track-popularity-a-series-of-checkboxes-on-a-webpage/133925#133925) to understand how to do it. The difference with your problem, is that you need to use a link element instead of a checkbox.

Good luck!